R and writing to JSON
Don't know if this is possible or if I'd have to do extra steps, but is there a way to export to a json file without the main square brackets:
[
    {
        "Name":"John",
        "Phone":"123-456-7890"
    }
]

Leaving something like this:
{
    "Name":"John",
    "Phone":"123-456-7890"
}

This is the closest I've gotten:
df <- data.frame (
  Name = c("John"),
  Phone = c("123-456-7890")
)
jsonlite::write_json(df,'test.json',pretty = TRUE)


What package are you using for write_json currently? Like toJSON(as.list(df), pretty=TRUE)  in jsonlite if you're open to that package?

note that to export single strings instead of lists with toJSON you will need to use jsonlite::unbox when creating the list

@thelatemail edited above

Use unbox
library(jsonlite)

toJSON(unbox(data.frame(Name = c("John"),
                        Phone = c("123-456-7890"))),
       auto_unbox = TRUE,
       pretty = TRUE)

Which gives:
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Phone": "123-456-7890"
  } 

If the result has to be written to a JSON file, one can simply replace toJSON with write_json:
write_json(unbox(data.frame(Name = c("John"),
                            Phone = c("123-456-7890"))),
           path = file.choose(),
           auto_unbox = TRUE,
           pretty = TRUE)


How would i keep the formatting when I write to a JSON file? When I go to do so it exports this: ["{\n    \"Name\": \"John\",\n    \"Phone\": 123-456-7890\n  }"]

I use jsonlite::write_json() to export

See my update. Using write_json does work for me, i.e. it doesn't export the squared brackets.

I think i overlooked the path=... then when i researching those functions. Thank you for your answer.
